# puttging special chars in a java string like "ctrl+insert"

Tags: java, string, ascii, non-ascii-characters, chars

## java strings problem:

I am trying to automate a process of special char typing (ctrl+insert)
using a java based system.
i have tried googling it with no luck
how do i include chars like these in a java string?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that "ctrl+insert" and many other keystrokes are not characters. Programs that respond to those keystrokes have to respond to the keystrokes as part of their responses to the system on which they run, they aren't reading "characters" to detect those.

Comment: thanks, if these are not characters, how does it pass via ssh?

Comment: I don't know how ssh works for this; perhaps an SSH client translates ctrl-insert to something useful, some special operations like that did have strings of characters as equivalents, though I don't know that ctrl-insert was one of them. The Insert key does not translate to a character just by itself, either. Sorry, don't know this one.